# How to keep labels displayed for all facet filters

Tags: 7, search

I have Search API with Facets API set up.  For my checkbox selections, how can I prevent the facets from hiding when they aren't available?  I want all of the facets to be listed, even if not available.

I can't seem to find an easy way to do this.

EDIT: I may have incorrectly used the term "facets" here. I mean to say filter options.  So, if blue, red, and green are options, but the only available results are blue, I still want red and green to display as check boxes.

Comment: You can fake it by making [Facet Blocks](http://getlevelten.com/blog/kyle-taylor/facet-block-unknown-hero) combined with Facet API Pretty Paths. Just rewrite the URLs in the view to go to the Facet path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set this option

[image]

on facet settings form.

Comment: That didn't work, but I see where someone actually submitted a patch for this today, so I'll run that and report back.

Comment: I added the patch from this issue to the search_api_db module: https://drupal.org/node/1658964, and set the Minimum facet count to 0.  My inactive filters now display.